# Why does use-package considers "emacs" as a package?

Tags: use-package

In the `use-package` documentation https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#diminishing-and-delighting-minor-modes there is an example that considers **emacs** as a package(i.e `(use-package emacs)`)

Usually the installed packages reside in the subdirectory of '~/.emacs.d/...'. How does use-package handle the package **emacs** ? Is it handled as a special case ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not packages that `use-package` loads but *features* (which are things you can `require` and test for with `featurep`).  From this point of view, `use-package` is essentially a fancy wrapper for `require`.

While `use-package` can often seem like magic, you can demystify by placing point after a `use-package` stanza and doing `M-x pp-macroexpand-last-sexp`.  In the case you reference, macro-expanding

```
(use-package emacs
  :delight
  (auto-fill-function " AF")
  (visual-line-mode))
```

yields

```
(if
    (not
     (require 'emacs nil t))
    (display-warning 'use-package
             (format "Cannot load %s" 'emacs)
             :error)
  (if
      (fboundp 'delight)
      (delight
       '((auto-fill-function " AF" emacs)
     (visual-line-mode nil emacs)))))
```

wrapped in some error-checking, messages and timing.

This is helpful: you can use the nice `use-package` interface to configure built-in things like `dired`.

Comment: So `(featurep 'emacs)` is true. (Who knew?) And the reason is...? I wonder.

Comment: I did not know until I tried it.  No idea why...

Comment: It can be a convenience when writing code which deals with features if there's a feature which is guaranteed to always be present.  Rather than dealing with special-cases, you can just supply the `emacs` feature.  I don't know for certain if this is the reason for it existing, but I think it's a good thing that it does.

Comment: I asked on help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org, and @stefan [replied](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2020-10/msg00308.html) saying *"`emacs` was added as a feature as a consequence of
`xemacs` being a feature."*