# Splitting use-package declarations in literate config

Tags: use-package, config, literate-programming

Trying to clean up my configuration and make it more readable, but also
reduce load time from current time of about 13 seconds down to < 10.

Suppose I have a large `use-package` macro for a package of this form:

```
(use-package foo
    :ensure t
    :defer t
    :init
    (do-something)
    :bind
    (<f5> . foo-fight)
    :config
    (setq bar)   )
```

I'd like to split this into three separate declarations like this:

```
(use-package foo
    :ensure t
    :defer t
    :init
    (do-something) )

(use-package foo
    :bind
    (<f5> . foo-fight) )

(use-package foo
    :config
    (setq bar) )
```

The idea is that each mini `use-package` macro is in it's own org-src
block, and I have some text outside annotating what it does, or links to
where I found the settings, or notes about changes. Additionally, when
running Emacs and making a set of changes to e.g. the keybindings of a
package, I could just go to that org-src block, edit the `sexp`s, and do
`C-c C-c` to update the config – rather than re-evaluate the entire config.

I want to ensure that `:defer t` isn't affected by splitting this. My experience implementing this so far is that this does work in some cases, but in others, splitting the `use-package` macro seems to lead to the package being loaded. Has anyone tried checking this and determining if this works or not?

I've seen e.g. [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/issues/662) discussing the same thing, which is a tentative yes. This [literate config](https://www.lucacambiaghi.com/vanilla-emacs/readme.html#h:83403D79-9668-48DC-82FB-98FAFFD7DF11) seems to implement this idea profusely.

There is also the suggestion of [using noweb to combine all org-src-block](https://github.com/zzamboni/dot-emacs/blob/master/init.org#org-mode) outputs for a package into a single `use-package` macro when tangling. That sounds great – even the proper way to do it – but it would require a lot of re-writing on my part at this time.

Comment: Have a look at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61276/why-does-use-package-considers-emacs-as-a-package/61277#61277 for how to understand what `use-package` is doing.  The main point is that `use-package` is a fancy wrapper around `require` and, thought of that way, it seems that multiple calls to `(use-package foo...)` is probably not the right way to go.

Comment: You can just split up the 'single' `use-package` macro over different blocks (although the opening parenthesis would be in the first block and the closing one in the last). However, I would suggest to consider using the elisp primitives. You will find that `use-package` really does not make things much easier (perhaps just a little, but the main advantage is the slightly more readable syntax. However, you are already using a nicely readable literate org file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the examples of [SqrtMinusOne's config](https://sqrtminusone.xyz/configs/emacs/) and [zzamboni's old config](https://github.com/zzamboni/dot-emacs/blob/master/init.org), I decided to use [Noweb](https://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-Reference-Syntax.html) to tangle different code blocks into a single `use-package` declaration for each package.

For example, I would have:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results silent :noweb no-export
(use-package mu4e
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :commands (mu4e)

  :config

   <<mu4e-config>>


   <<mu4e-contexts>>



   )

#+end_src
```

and then, at a more convenient location in my literate `.org` file, I would have the block:

```
#+name: mu4e-config
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results silent :tangle no
(require 'smtpmail)


(setq mu4e-maildir "~/maildir"
      mu4e-get-mail-command "mbsync GrMil"
      mu4e-update-interval 300
      mu4e-view-show-images t
      mu4e-view-scroll-to-next nil
      mu4e-use-fancy-chars t
      mu4e-attachment-dir "~/Downloads"
      mu4e-change-filenames-when-moving t
      mu4e-sent-messages-behavior 'delete
      mu4e-headers-date-format "%+4Y-%m-%d"
      message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      )
#+end_src
```

where the value of the `#+name:` block header is the one that is referred to within `<< >>` in the `use-package` block.

It took a while to re-factor my config, but I think it was worth it in the end.